# Controlling mp3 module in basic stamp 2

Tags: basic

Does anyone here has an experience in basic stamp programming? We have a device that uses a `PIC16C57C` and `mp3` modules (CY-T16 V1.0). My main goal here is to change the `PIC` to basic stamp 2. I need to use basic stamp 2 to control the `mp3` module.

Comment: Did you have a specific question that you wanted to ask ?

Comment: Yes. I want to know on how to control the mp3 module by using basic stamp 2. does anyone here has a knowledge or background with that kind of project?